# Load template attribute in AngularJS directive for $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-templates

I am new using angularjs and I am trying to create directives. My query is, how can I change the URL of the `$http.get` from the html. This is my code:

**HTML directive:**

```
<form-directive text="Formulario con Directiva" nameinput="true"
                namelabel="Nombre:" emailinput="true"
                emaillabel="Email:" subjetinput="true" subjetlabel="Asunto:" 
                message="true" messagelabel="Mensaje:"
                dataurl="URL to change">
</form-directive>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    angular.module('testDirective', [])
        .controller('testDir', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.textoFalopa = "Hola, es una prueba";
        })
        .directive('formDirective', function () {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                templateUrl: './template.html',
                scope: {
                    text: '@',
                    nameinput: '=nameinput',
                    namelabel: '@',
                    emailinput: '=emailinput',
                    emaillabel: '@',
                    subjetinput: '=subjetinput',
                    subjetlabel: '@',
                    message: '=message',
                    messagelabel: '@',
                    dataurl:'='
                },
                controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function (remotedata) {
                        console.log(remotedata.data);
                        $scope.data = remotedata.data;
                    });
                }],
                link: function (scope) {
                    console.log(scope);
                }
            };
        });

</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You mean change your $http.get call from JavaScript, not from HTML right?

Comment: It would be wiser to re-factor the app to have the parent controller fetch the data from the server. Avoid asynchronous operations in the form component as it makes testing and debugging difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you are looking to do is to get the value of the attribute on your directive declaration `dataurl="URL to change"` and use that as the URL in the $http call.

The properties in the `scope` object define the bindings of these attributes to your AngularJS scope (injected as `$scope`).

You have already bound `dataurl` to your scope, so you're half way there. Now the the most straightforward way of getting the in the example you have posted would be to just use the `$scope` object in your controller. Like so:

```
angular.module('testDirective').directive('formDirective', function () {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                templateUrl: './template.html',
                scope: {
                    text: '@',
                    nameinput: '=nameinput',
                    namelabel: '@',
                    emailinput: '=emailinput',
                    emaillabel: '@',
                    subjetinput: '=subjetinput',
                    subjetlabel: '@',
                    message: '=message',
                    messagelabel: '@',
                    dataurl:'='
                },
                controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($element, $http) {
                    $http.get($scope.dataurl).then(function (remotedata) {
                        console.log(remotedata.data);
                    });
                }]
            };
        });
```

Be advised that best practice with AngularJS is now to only use `$scope` directly when needing it's advanced features. For this kind of simple case you shouldn't need to inject it. I would suggest looking into AngularJS [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and/or the `bindToController` [property](https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/).

An alternative (but perhaps messy) solution if you just want to get the attribute is to inject `$element` which gives you access to the underlying jQuery object.

```
angular.module('testDirective').directive('formDirective', function () {
            return {
                restrict: "EA",
                templateUrl: './template.html',
                controller: ['$element', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get($element.attr('dataurl')).then(function (remotedata) {
                        console.log(remotedata.data);
                    });
                }]
            };
        });
```

Though this isn't really the 'angular way' so I'd only use it for quick hacks or messy workarounds.

So you have three approaches there. Any one will work, but I would suggest learning components and controller binding as that will encourage good practice and put you in good stead for learning Angular 2+